# Google ProtoBuffer: Limit size of message

Tags: java, limit, protocol-buffers

Are there any options to limit size of input output messages in protobuffer ?
For example I have two messages like `In` and `Out`each of these messages contains required byte array `bytes` and into this array I can write a lot of bytes, so, I want to limit size of this array for example to 1Mb How can I to do it?

**EDIT**

I've found class `CodedInputStream` and method `pushLimit`, but I cannot edit generated sources to set up limit using this method, how to do it from `.proto` message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by yourself by making a threshold size`(int MAXIMUM_SIZE = 1045876;)`. while reading or writing byte array create byte array which size will be at max that of `MAXIMUM_SIZE` which you have specified.

Comment: I have found a few ways how I can to do it, but all these ways are manually, my question was how and can I to do it using protobuffer.

Comment: For example I can use CodedInputStream method pushLimit, but how i did not found.